# Assembly language using signed int multiplication math to perform shifts

Tags: algorithm, assembly, bit-shift, motorola, integer-arithmetic

This is a bit of a turn around.

Usually one is attempting to use shifts to perform multiplication and not the other way around.

On the Hitachi/Motorola 6309 there is no shift by n bits.  There is only shift by 1 bit.

However there is a 16 bit x 16 bit signed multiply (provides a 32 bit signed result).

(EDIT)  Using this is no problem for a 16 bit shift (left) however I'm trying to use 2 x 16x16 signed mults to do a 32 bit shift.  The high order word of the result for the low order word shift is the problem. (Does that make sence?)

Some pseudo code might help:

```
result.highword = low word of (val.highword * shiftmulttable[shift])
temp = val.lowword * shiftmulttable[shift]
result.lowword = temp.lowword
result.highword = or (result.highword, temp.highword)
(with some magic on temp.highword to consider signed values)
```

I have been exercising my logic in an attempt to use this instruction to perform the shifts but so far I have failed.

I can easily achieve any positive value shifts by 0 to 14 but when it comes to shifting by 15 bits (mult by 0x8000) or shifting any negative values certain combinations of values require either:

- complementing the result by 1
- complementing the result by 2
- adding 1 to the result
- doing nothing to the result

And I just can't see any pattern to these values.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: What result do you expect when shift value 3 by 15 bits? `3 * 0x8000 = 3 * -32768 = -98304 = FFFE:8000` or `-32768` in low word

Comment: A 6309 can do a shift in 2 cycles, while a multiply takes 28, so you're probably not better off using it.   For shifts greater than 7 you can speed it up by first "shifting" entire bytes by moving them.

Comment: @ross 2 cycles per shift.  Times 4 bytes times upto 31 bit shifts equals 2 x 4 x 31 or 248 cycles and that's not counting the loop construct of 31 x 6 cycles

Comment: @WallyZ: One can easily synthesize an *unsigned* 16x16->32 bit multiply from an existing *signed* 16x16->32 bit multiply instruction by applying a correction to the most significant half of the product. It seems to me that would solve your problem?

Comment: My comment already addressed how to perform shifts greater than 7 more efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best I can tell from the problem description, implementing the 32-bit shift would work as desired by using an *unsigned* 16x16->32 bit multiply. This can easily be synthesized from a signed 16x16->32 multiply instruction by exploiting the two's complement integer representation. If the two factors are `a` and `b`, adding `b` to the high-order 16 bits of the signed product when `a` is negative, and adding `a` to the high-order 16 bits of the signed product when `b` is negative will give us the unsigned multiplication result.

The following C code implements this approach and tests it exhaustively:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* signed 16x16->32 bit multiply. Hardware instruction */
int32_t mul16_wide (int16_t a, int16_t b)
{
    return (int32_t)a * (int32_t)b;
}

/* unsigned 16x16->32 bit multiply (synthetic) */
int32_t umul16_wide (int16_t a, int16_t b)
{
    int32_t p = mul16_wide (a, b); // signed 16x16->32 bit multiply
    if (a < 0) p = p + (b << 16);  // add 'b' to upper 16 bits of product
    if (b < 0) p = p + (a << 16);  // add 'a' to upper 16 bits of product
    return p;
}

/* unsigned 16x16->32 bit multiply (reference) */
uint32_t umul16_wide_ref (uint16_t a, uint16_t b)
{
     return (uint32_t)a * (uint32_t)b;
}

/* test synthetic unsigned multiply exhaustively */
int main (void)
{
    int16_t a, b;
    int32_t res, ref;
    uint64_t count = 0;

    a = -32768;
    do {
        b = -32768;
        do {
            res = umul16_wide (a, b);
            ref = umul16_wide_ref (a, b);
            count++;
            if (res != ref) {
                printf ("!!!! a=%d b=%d res=%d ref=%d\n", a, b, res, ref);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            if (b == 32767) break;
            b = b + 1;
        } while (1);
        if (a == 32767) break;
        a = a + 1;
    } while (1);
    printf ("test cases passed: %llx\n", count);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am not familiar with the Hitachi/Motorola 6309 architecture. I assume it uses a special 32-bit register to hold the result of a wide multiply, from which high and low half can be extracted into 16-bit general-purpose registers, and the conditional corrections can then be applied to the register holding the upper 16 bits.

Comment: It's not rare for full-multiply instructions to simply have 2 normal GP integer registers as the destination; sometimes implicit (x86 `mul` writes EDX:EAX) or explicit (like ARM where multiply instructions take two destination operands).  Or the even register number of a register-pair.  MIPS's special `lo/hi` registers are not that common, and is mostly explained by  aggressively applying RISC design philosophy with fixed 1c latency for simple instructions, but still wanting a HW multiply.  A microcontroller probably isn't like that.  So probably it's even easier to get the high/low results.

Comment: @Peter Corded: I now pulled the Programmer's Reference for this processor and it shows a special 32-bit register called "Accumulator Q" which receives the result of a `MULD` instruction. There must be instructions for transferring data into and out of this special register, but I haven't found them yet ... Looks like it needs to be stored to memory with `STQ`.

Comment: Interesting, maybe instruction-encoding limitations explain not just using GP integer regs.  (And/or that Ross Ridge pointed out multiply costs 28 cycles.  Although IDK if it's pipelined and supports out-of-order completion of instructions.)  Maybe hi/lo regs aren't as rare as I assumed.

Comment: Ok so I have some working 6309 assembler code now and the cycle difference between the muld (signed mult) and using conventional lsl (logical shift left) to perform 32 bit shift of 1,16,31 bits is.  For muld 197 cycles.  For lsl 108, 1368, 2628.  A shift amount of anything more than 1 and the signed mult wins.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using fixed-point multiplicative inverses to use the high half result for a right shift?

If you're just left-shifting, multiply by `0x8000` should work.  **The low half of an NxN => 2N-bit multiply is the same whether inputs are treated as signed or unsigned.**  Or do you need a 32-bit shift result from your 16-bit input?

Is the multiply instruction actually faster than a few 1-bit shifts for small shift counts?  (I wouldn't be surprised if compile-time-constant counts of 2 or 3 would be faster with just a chain of 2 or 3 `add same,same` or left-shift instructions.)

---

Anyway, **for a compile-time-constant shift count of 15**, maybe just multiply by `1<<14` and then **do the last count with a 1-bit shift (`add same,same`)**.

Or if your ISA has rotates, rotate right by 1 and mask away the low bits, skipping the multiply.  Or zero a register, right-shift the low bit into the carry flag, then rotate-through-carry into the top of the zeroed register.

(The latter might be useful on an ISA that doesn't have large immediates and couldn't "mask away all the low bits" in one instruction.  Or an ISA that only has RCR not ROR.  I don't know 6309 at all)

---

If you're using **a runtime count to look up a multiplier from a table**, maybe branch for that case, or adjust your LUT so every entry needs an extra 1-bit shift, so you can do `mul(lut[count])` and an unconditional extra shift.

(Only works if you don't need to support a shift-count of zero.)

Comment: These are all good suggestions (+1), but the signedness of a 16x16->32 bit multiplication only affects the high-order 16 bits, while the low-order 16-bits  represent the properly shifted result, even when the shift count is 15 (multiplier of 0x8000) That is, I don't see the problem. Example: 0x8000 * 0x0003 = 0xFFFE:0x8000, where 0x8000 is (0x3 << 15), i..e the desired result.

Comment: @njuffa: oh yes, good point!  Now that you point that out, the question makes no sense if it's just left-shifting.  Maybe they *are* right shifting by using the high half result for fixed-point multiplicative inverses?  But then `mult 0x8000` wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @njuffa: I wonder if they want a 32-bit shift result, equivalent to sign-extending the value to be shifted and then doing a 32-bit left shift?

Comment: Yes shifting left. 16 bit shifts are not the problem.  I'm trying do 32 bit shifts using 2 x 16x16 mults and as njuffa have suggested it is the high order word that is causing the problem.  cordes Yes I tried a <<14 and add same,same as well.

Comment: @WallyZ: oh.  Well that's a pretty different question.  You should edit your question to actually ask it clearly.  (Don't worry about invalidating my answer; it's answering a problem that doesn't really exist.)  Does 6309 have 32-bit registers, or is the 32-bit result split across 2 registers?  Does it have add-with-carry to let you easily shift a bit out the top of the low half, and into the bottom of the high half?

Comment: It's not just the multiplier than can be negative (0x8000), the value can also be negative and both can be negative (which I thought would cancel out but causes a lot of problems for some reason)

Comment: @WallyZ: Since you've already done some of the work thinking through the problems, *update your question* with some specific examples we can look at and think about.  Still, if you're just use the low-half results of multiplies for each of the 16-bit halves of a 32-bit value to be shifted, signedness literally doesn't matter.  It only affects the high-half result.

Answer (score 0):

Not that there would be many interested people who would want to see the 6309 code, but here it is:

Compliant with OS9 C ABI.

Pointer to result and arguments pushed on stack right to left.

```
U,PC,val(4bytes),shift(2bytes),*result(2bytes)
0 2  4           8              10
```

:

```
* 10,s pointer to long result
* 4,s 4 byte value
* 8,s 2 byte shift
* x = pointer to result
  pshs u
  ldx 10,s * load pointer to result
  ldd 8,s * load shift
* if shift amount is greater than 31 then
* just return zero.  OS9 C standard.
  cmpd #32
  blt _10x
  ldq #0
  stq 4,s
  bra _13x
* if shift amount is greater than 16 than
* move bottom word of value into top word 
* and clear bottom word  
_10x
  cmpb #16
  blt _1x
  ldu 6,s
  stu 4,s
  clr 6,s
  clr 7,s
_1x
* setup pointer u and offset e into mult table _2x
  leau _2x,pc
  andb #15
* if there is no shift value just return value
  beq _13x
  aslb * need to double shift to use as word table offset
  stb 8,s     * save double shft
  tfr b,e 
* shift top word q = val.word.high * multtab[shft]
  ldd 4,s
  muld e,u
  stw ,x * result.word.high = low word of mult
* shift bottom word q = val.word.low * multtab[shft]
  lde 8,s     * reload double shft
  ldd 6,s
  muld e,u
  stw 2,x     * result.word.low = low word of mult
* The high word or mult needs to be corrected for sign
* if val is negative then muld will return negated results
* and need to un negate it
  lde 8,s     * reload double shift
  tst 4,s     * test top byte of val for negative
  bge _11x
  addd e,u    * add the multtab[shft] again to top word 
_11x
* if multtab[shft] is negative (shft is 15 or shft<<1 is 30)
* also need to un negate result
  cmpe #30
  bne _12x
  addd 6,s    * add val.word.low to top word
_12x
* combine top and bottom and save bottom half of result 
  ord ,x
  std ,x
  bra _14x
* this is only reached if the result is in value (let result = value) 
_13x
  ldq 4,s     * load value
  stq ,x      * result = value
_14x
  puls u,pc
_2x fdb $01,$02,$04,$08,$10,$20,$40,$80,$0100,$0200,$0400,$0800
   fdb $1000,$2000,$4000,$8000
```